# Error updating from 14.02 LTS to 16.0 LTS

Tags: 16.04, updates

I am attempting to updating Ubuntu 14.02 LTS to 16.04 LTS and I am receiving the following error:

It was not possible to authenticate some packages. this may be a transient network problem. See below for a list of unauthenticated packages.

linux-signed-image-generic

How do I address this issue? It has been awhile since I have updated my Ubuntu so I don't know what to do necessarily.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Please check that you internet connection is ok! And did you do an update on the Ubuntu Trusty before an upgrade to Xenial?

Comment: Internet connection is good! I don't think so. Ubuntu asked if I wanted to update and I clicked the yes option and I got this error after obtaining the necessary files to update (I think). It just won't continue because of this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check that you internet connection is ok! And did you do an update on the Ubuntu Trusty before an upgrade to Xenial? – George 5 hours ago